# Store intermediate form data

Tags: database, http, web-applications, httpsession

In a web application, we often come across a form submission process that spans across several pages, for ex: In first form we capture basic information, next page capture some other information and so on. I have a scenario where I've 7 screens to capture all the details about user and "Submit" button appears on 7th page.

Usually we store all the intermediate values in HttpSession and when its time to submit we retrieve all the values from Session and create an entry in database.

With this approach, by the time user completes all the form entries (i.e. from Page 1 to Page 7), everything resides in Session.

I would like to know, is there any alternative apart from HttpSession for storing the intermediate values?

I'm actually trying to find the ways to make my HttpSession less bulky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also store just the reference in a session which then maps to a cache like e.g. [Memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached). Or if it is important that you don't lose the data while the user walks through the steps, you can also persist the data in a database and just refer via a key from a session to it. To store too much data in the session is sometimes not the best choice, so I would just store a reference there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try **[caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx)** technology of .Net, this might be useful instead of using session for all the data, also you can just use the id of the session for the cache id.

Second option I think is **[configuring your Session-State mode to use SQLServer mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)** for the storage.